FormData not appending files in angular
I am trying to upload file using FormData so that I can send through a HTTP Request. This is my HTML code
<ng-template #displayApp>
    <div class="display flex justify-content-center">
        <div >
            <p-fileUpload 
            chooseLabel="Select First File"
            [showUploadButton]="false"
            [showCancelButton]="false"        
            (onSelect)="checkFilesSelected()"
            (onRemove)="checkFilesSelected()"
            #originalFile>
            </p-fileUpload>
        </div>

        <div style="margin: 0 20px;"></div>

        <div >
            <p-fileUpload 
            chooseLabel="Select Second File"
            [showUploadButton]="false"
            [showCancelButton]="false"             
            (onSelect)="checkFilesSelected()"
            (onRemove)="checkFilesSelected()"
            #revisedFile>
            </p-fileUpload>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;"> </div>
    <div class="display flex justify-content-center">
        <p-button [disabled]="!areFilesSelected" (click)="onUpload()">Compare Files</p-button>
    </div>
</ng-template>

I am selecting two files and trying to upload both the files in single call so that they are in sync with each other.
This is my component TS file.
  @ViewChild('firstFile') firstFile!: FileUpload;
  @ViewChild('secondFile') secondFile!: FileUpload;

onUpload() {
    console.log("File upload called",);

    const originalFiles: File = this.originalFile.files[0]
    const revisedFiles: File[] = this.revisedFile.files;
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();

    console.log("First ",originalFiles, originalFiles.name)
    debugger;

    formData.append('First', originalFiles)
    console.log("Form Data ", formData)

    let uploadUrl = new URL('baseURL');

    uploadUrl.searchParams.append('First',"first");
    uploadUrl.searchParams.append('Second',"second");  

    this.http.post(uploadUrl.toString(), formData).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log('File uploaded successfully:', response);
      },
      error => {
        console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
      }
    );
  }

I can see that originalFiles is getting populated with the file details. But when I am appending it to formData is does not get appended and neither throws any exception.  When I see formData on console it is empty.
Any help on this?
I tried to change that data type to File instead of FileUpload but it did not turn out to be working anyway. If we use event.Files[0] then it appends file just fine. I am not sure how can I combine this event into single so I can upload files.

Does this answer your question? How to inspect FormData?

@YongShun it does not.

To use form data in angular the enctype header must be set and for the checking out the values present in the FormData the entries method does work.
onUpload() {
  console.log("File upload called");

  const originalFiles: File = this.originalFile.files[0]
  const revisedFiles: File[] = this.revisedFile.files;
  
  let formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append('First', originalFiles);

  // log each entry in the formData
  for (const [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
  }

  let uploadUrl = new URL('baseURL');
  uploadUrl.searchParams.append('First', "first");
  uploadUrl.searchParams.append('Second', "second");

  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'enctype': 'multipart/form-data' });

  this.http.post(uploadUrl.toString(), formData, { headers: headers }).subscribe(
    response => {
      console.log('File uploaded successfully:', response);
    },
    error => {
      console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
    }
  );
}

